# Google Optimize snippet on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics

I would like to add Google Optimize snippet on my Magento 1.9.3.1 site. I added the Optimize snippet to the site via Admin -> System -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> HTML Head. However, the snippet does not register with Google. Screenshot below. Code snippet below. How can we fix this issue?

[image]

> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
>     (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
>     m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
>     })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
>     ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'auto');
>     ga('require', 'GTM-XXXXX');
>     ga('send', 'pageview');

Comment: This is a legitimate question, please make available to the community. Thank you.

Comment: I can see why this was closed, but I agree with you in that it is something that will be searched for more and more.  I've answered the question here with a module that caters for your request - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167407/updating-analytics-code-for-google-optimize/188411#188411